# What is the best way in JavaScript to search keywords into .txt files stored at AWS S3?

Tags: javascript, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wanted to search the case insensitive keywords into .txt files stored at AWS S3. I have around 4k-5k .txt files at AWS s3 in which I wanted to search for keywords.

I tried searching keywords by downloading each file buffer and by applying JavaScript contains() method on each buffer. It gives me results but very slow.

Then I thought to download all files locally first and then apply Regex search locally but downloading 4k-5k .txt files also can take time.

Is there any best way to search keywords in this scenario. Please help me with your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You've got few options to fulfill your requirement:

1) Using aws service called - [Cloud Search](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/getting-started-uploading-data.html)

2) AWS CLI: There are cli tools like [Boto](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) or [Javascript Node](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html) cli tools

for Keyword search: ( Assuming this is your case)
aws s3api list-objects --bucket myBucketName --prefix "keyword"

for String Patter:

aws s3api list-objects --bucket myBucketName --query "Contents[?contains(Key, `searchPattern`)]"

Comment: I could have used cloud search but I can't for pricing reasons. Querying "Contents[?contains(Key, searchPattern)]" can be helpful for me but I don't know how I can implement this in node.js.
Thank you for responding

Comment: Can you describe more about the size of the individual txt files that you are trying to search and how frequently does something get added or removed. Based on that a better alternative architecture can be looked at like - having a combined txt file and lambda's triggering any changes to the files. Something efficient than opening individual files and searching through them.

Comment: One .txt file is not too large possible will have around 2k characters in a file and the content of file never gets changed. I could have combined all files and then search into a single file but the problem is I need to find out in which file I found the matching keyword.